# Improve quality of the grained curves in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, bezier-curve

I would like to know how to improve my grained curves.

Thanks in advance,

André

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTION A**

Use the blur tool.

You'll have to do this manually, select the blur tool and make it 2-3 pixel in size, about 50% strength and go on the side of the edge, not on the edge it self.

If you feel it takes away the sharpness (which it will) you can reduce the strength or make the brush smaller.

**OPTION B**

Use the pen tool to trace the curve and create a mask. Then take the color picker tool and select the appropriate color from the image and use the brush tool to sharpen the edge out.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the pen tool and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

The best would to prevent these to get a birth. They seem like the Magic Wand or the Select Color Range has been used for selections when

- making luminosity /contrast /color adjustments
- cutting parts for composing a collage

The selections for these purposes should be done with tools that give sharp edges regardless the sharpness of the contrast and color borders.

**But how to clean** if all the available stuff has ragged edges, no way to redo all properly? The solution is to recreate the sharp borders. Draw selections with a sharp edge tool (=polygonal lasso, pen+convert work path to selection, quick selection tool+refine edge, elliptical and rectangular marquees, combining several selections, inverting) and

- repaint the areas by a solid brush (pick the color!) or
- clone on them from a good place or
- push good color against the selection borded by smudge tool

Your new edge may be unrealistic sharp. That is easily fixed by the Blur tool, use about 40% strength

The gradients that create an illusion of 3D are difficult to fix. I've a few times made a fill with solid color. The gradient may be unnecessary, but if it is needed, you can make a selection that consists the area of the gradient. Then blur it by the gaussian blur, The blurring takes stuff from the other side of the selection border, but doesn't itself spread over.

[image]

The foot is repainted onto a new layer. Thislike stuff is easy to repaint if you do not have to be accurate, only plausible. The old was painted over with grey when the new was ready

Still remember: The ragged edges can be prevented to born. That's the lowest harm way.